# How to best(most efficiently) read the first sheet in Excel file into Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

Loading the excel file using read_excel takes quite long. Each Excel file has several sheets. The first sheet is pretty small and is the sheet I'm interested in but the other sheets are quite large and have graphs in them. Generally this wouldn't be a problem if it was one file, but I need to do this for potentially thousands of files and pick and combine the necessary data together to analyze. If somebody knows a way to efficiently load in the file directly or somehow quickly make a copy of the Excel data as text that would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for [pandas.read_excel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html). You can use `sheet_name=0` to read in only the first sheet.

Comment: That's the default that I ran it at. I'm guessing read_excel in general just takes awhile to run. For one file it's probably taking around 45sec-1min to load which isn't feasible to do for thousands of files unfortunately.

Comment: how big is a single sheet of this file? does the performance differ on a smaller file?

Comment: The sheet that I'm interested in is only about 3kb when converted to CSV while the other sheets are 5000kb-20,000kb with about 10 of them in each workbook. The sheet that I'm interested is poorly structured so read_excel stores the dataframe in an odd way(not sure if that would affect its performance in anyway). Ultimately, I think this may best be tackled by using VBA to batch save the Excel sheets as CSV and parse the text file for the data I need.

Answer (score -1):

The method read_excel() reads the data into a Pandas Data Frame, where the first parameter is the filename and the second parameter is the sheet.

df = pd.read_excel('File.xlsx', sheetname='Sheet1')